# Why middle variable faster then direct use property

Tags: javascript, performance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a" class="xxx"></div>

  <script>
    const ele = document.querySelector('#a')

    function foo(ele, cls) {
      return ele.className === cls
    }

    function bar(ele, cls) {
      const clsname = ele.className
      return clsname === cls
    }

    console.info(foo(ele, 'xxx'));
    console.info(bar(ele, 'xxx'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I compared foo and bar in jsbench, result is bar is faster than foo. Why? Function bar has one more step than foo, why it is still faster?

[image]

Comment: How much faster are we talking? Jsbench also gives uncertainty/precision percentages that might make the results off a little.

Comment: I ran this through jsbench.me a few times and the results were back and forth - less than a % between the two on most occasions. While I don't know what's going on under the hood behind optimizations and the benchmark site, I wouldn't take one result as a given especially with the results so close.